# How to close of other functions in JQuery Toogle

Tags: jquery

I am using

```
$(".archived").click(function(){
    $(".archivedtable").toggle();
});
```

I have a bunch of tables that will be opened based on which nav link is selected, so if they select 1, 1 will open.  Lets say than they select 2, 2 will open also but 1 is still open.  So I was wondering how to make it so 1 would go away and 2 would be the new active one.  Does this make sense?

UPDATE:

```
if ($paid == 1 && $securitylevel == 1 && $csvuser != 1){

    $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, status, statuschangedate FROM csvdata WHERE memberview =:username ORDER BY lastname";
    $sth= $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));
    $i=0;
    echo "<table class='nonothertable'> 
    <tr class='firsttr' style='background:gray;'>
    <td>First Name </td>
    <td>Last Name </td>
    <td>Email </td>
    <td>Phone </td>
    <td>Username </td>
    <td>Password </td>
    <td>Status </td>
 <td>Status Change Date</td>
    <td>#</td>
     </tr>
    ........

     echo "
      </table>";
}
 <script>
$(".nonother").click(function(){
    $(".nonothertable").toggle();
});
</script>
```

So these tables that are populated by PHP, I have a ton of them and after each one is the script as you see above that will open and close the particular one.  I want to know how to, once I click one, if there is another one open that once will close.

They are all in a div, some are nested in another div.  All have same parent.

NOTE:

Please note that every single table populated has a different name and different attribute to access it.

Comment: In the click handler, close (hide, whatever) all elements which should be closed.

Comment: Post relevant HTML. Is this nav link is inside the same container as `archievedtable`? If yes, you can simply use `context` or `.find` and toggle the specific table.

Comment: No, this does'nt make sense. Post some HTML and descibe it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, for your specific code

just add

```
$("table").not(".current-one").hide();
```

before your .toggle();

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tables = $("table");
var $butons = $(".tableSelector");

$butons.click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var $currentTable = $("."+$t.attr("class")+"table").show();
    $tables.not($currentTable).hide();
});
```

Comment: you need separate before buttons and tables :)

Comment: first version was not separate buttons and table, here i assume a data-table atribute contains linked table identifier, so button click show you the right table

Comment: The table is using a class, is that okay?

Comment: ok, re edited to use your class selector, but use class is not good, try id or just index if tables and butons are in the same order ?

Comment: var $tables = $("Openstatustable");
var $butons = $(".viewstatus");

$butons.click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var $currentTable = $("."+$t.attr("class")+"Openstatustable").show();
    $tables.not($currentTable).hide();
});

Comment: if your butons contain more than one class it will not work, use other thing as identifier, data- is just great for that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24342/discussion-between-david-biga-and-r043v)

Answer (score 0):

As you control the links to open & tables generation, i think you have to many JS calls in your code. Just give tables a common class and a different name, and create the links according to the table names.

I don't see the buttons (clickable elements) generation code in your sample, so you can then do something like this:

Inside the loop, where mytableX is an unique name (replace X with database ID or unique number:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='togglers'>Open table X</a>";
echo "<table class='nonothertable' id='mytableX'>"
....
echo "</table>";
```

Tables should be hidden by default, using CSS

```
.nonothertable { display:none; }
```

Then, with just one call to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".togglers").click(function(){
        $(".nonothertable").hide(); // Hide all tables
        $(this).next('.nonothertable').show(); // Show the table next to the link we just clicked
        return false; // Avoid page jumps
    });    
});
</script>
```

At each click, we hide all tables, show the one next to our link, and avoid page jumps. Just one JS call for unlimited number of tables.

Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SHcjQ/

Comment: How would I use this?  I have a link that if click triggers the toggle for the table, the tables are not the same names.  They are each different

Comment: Ok, you updated the question, i'm going to update the answer, just a minute please

Answer (score -1):

When a number is selected, I would run through a loop that closes all of the tables, then I would open the selected table.

Comment: Ok, then maybe in your Javascript you could have a variable "CurrentlyOpenedTable" that has the class of the currently opened table. In the click function you can first check this variable and if it has anything in it, toggle the table in the variable (that should close it), toggle the clicked one to open it, and put the class of the newly opened one into the variable?